# How can I log out from here?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

My problem: I do not have my user name link on top of page-
I have only my profile picture- how can I log out? any idea?
I log in via gmail.

Thank you!

Comment: Click on `StackExchange` and then `Log out`.